# Github workflow actions Powershell not showing output

Tags: powershell

I am currently running on "windows-latest".

I am trying to run a windows executable file in powershell in a github workflow file.
I have a step that says

```
name: Check exe
      run: |
        .\file.exe
```

Where file.exe is the executable that I want to run.

However,
when "Check exe" step is run and it runs "./file.exe" in the github workflow action, there isn't any output, which there should be. I know this file exist because it does run when I test it out and have verified that this file is a valid executable.
How can I view the output of this executable in a github workflow action.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/types-of-cmdlet-output?view=powershell-7.3